# Unable to access (an save) my SpreadSheet Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google SpreadSheet (filled through a form) associated to a Google Apps Script.

Now, the spreadsheet contains too many cells and I'm not able to load it anymore (server timeout).

I'm not interested in the data, but I really want to retrieve the script (the source code).
Unfortunately, the only way I know is to load the SpreadSheet first :-(

(Copying the Document ends in a timeout and the script is not copied.)

Any suggestion?

Regards,

Rémi.

Comment: FYI, I have posted the same question on the [Google Spreadsheet Forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/docs/spreadsheets/WxzkBT0SumQ)

Answer (score 0):

Create another script which makes a copy of original spreadsheet to backup the data and then clear the original spreadsheet through the script.

However this seems an issue which should be reported to [Google Spreadsheet Forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/docs/spreadsheets)

Here is an example code which will backup the spreadsheet as a copy and clear the original spreadsheet

```
function backupDataAndClear(){
  var sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID_OF_ORIGINAL_SS');
  var newSS = sourceSS.copy('Backup SS');
  var sourceSheets = sourceSS.getSheets();
  for(var i in sourceSheets){
    sourceSheets[i].clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is ID_OF_ORIGINAL_SS the value of the key parameter in the SpreadSheet URL ? In that case, the script stops after a while with `Document ... is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)`

Comment: Your script works fine with a small spreadsheet, but not with my original one (certainly ending up with a timeout interpreted like a `Document is missing`)...

Comment: It seems like you are using a wrong spreadsheet ID. Please check it carefully if you have copied right ssKey. Else you can report it to Apps Script Issue tracker

Comment: I checked it twice, the ssKey was right. But I finally succeeded in loading my SpreadSheet (probably during a small activity period on the server) and retrieving my script :-). Anyway, thank you for your help, Waqar.